# Merge two similar GIT repositories but exclude specific directories

Tags: git, merge, repository

I have 2 git repositories(e.g. A and B) with similar directory structure but during the merging of branch "DEV", from A to B, i want to exclude specific directories/files/directory structures that exist in A but not in B.

For each file that is already present in both A and B and i would like to keep the version from repo B i have a .gitattributes file in each directory containing such files and i include a line for each file such as `routes-repo.ts  merge=ours`.

Currently i follow the below process:

1. run `git config merge.ours.driver true`
2. In the directory root of project B run `git fetch A DEV`
3. run `git fetch A DEV`
4. run `git merge A/DEV`

The above does sync the repositories but everything new that exists in project A is also synced to repo B. The sync is only done from A to B but not the reverse.

How can i exclude specific files/directories from the sync?

Comment: So if a file exists in A and B, you keep the version in B; and you don't want files that are in A but not in B (and the problem with the current procedure is you're getting those things)...  Then what information are you taking from A?

Comment: Ideally i would like to sync everything that exists in A into repo B except the following 2 cases.

1. Thr files that i include in .gitattributes files(this one works)
2. Specific files or directories that exist in A but i don't want them present in B. E.g. i have a directory in the root of my project named dir1 that is not present in the root of B. I want to find a way to say ignore dir1 during the merging. Not sure if .gitignore will satisfy this.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, looking at your work tree a file at a time, there are three cases:

1) Files that exist in both repos, but you want the version from Repo B; you have a solution for this

2) Certain files that exist only in A, which you want to leave out of the merge; you don't have a solution for this yet

3) Everything else, which can merge normally

So focusing on (2), you wonder (in comments) if .gitignore will help.  It won't.  The ignore rules only affect how git treats untracked files; it doesn't do anything on merges.

Because the files don't exist in Repo B, there will be no file merge, so using .gitattributes to set a merge handler won't work either.

**So what *will* work?**

You could issue the merge command with the `--no-commit` option.

```
git merge --no-commit A/DEV
```

This will tentatively complete the merge exactly the way it looks now, but it won't automatically generate a merge commit.  Instead it will stop and let you make whatever changes you want.  So

```
git rm -r a/directory/you/wanted/to/exclude
# ... etc
git commit
```

You might prefer something more automatic, especially if the merge will be repeated going forward.  I don't have a perfect solution for that.  You can expect that files you deleted during the 1st merge should "stay deleted", though you will get a merge conflict if Repo A has made further changes to the file.  (You could try including a path like `a/directory/you/wanted/to/exclude/**/* merge=ours` in a .gitattributes file at the work tree root; it might help.)

But if Repo A creates new files in those directories between merges, then you're back to having to manually remove those in the merge process (because git thinks in terms of files, not directories).

You could possibly set up a merge hook in repo B, to at least warn you when clean-up is needed.

Comment: Thanks Mark your solution sounds logical. I will try it and if possible will try to automate it to some extend. If i manage to implement it i will post it here.

Comment: On the point of automation, I suppose the way these commands work, a shell script that runs the `merge --no-commit ...`, then the `git rm ...`, then the `git commit` would *more or less* do the job; error handling is the pitfall I see